# How to run a client - server application on my mobile device?

Tags: android

I have a client - server application which I developed and tested on my pc where I use a certain port number and the IP "10.0.2.2" now I wanna move the client to my android device which is located on the same wifi network as my pc ... what do I need to change ?

Comment: Your post gives me the impression that you don't know the first thing about developing for the Android.  You might want to start with a tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: While not the only possibility, your use of "10.0.2.2" makes it sound like you have already been running your code on an Android emulator, and using that address which on the Android emulator is a special alias for the development machine's loopback interface.  If that is correct, you are nearly ready to run on a device - you just need to make sure that your server listens on a public interface, and use the actual IP address of the PC on the wifi network in place of the special alias.

Comment: I get it thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to port it to android platform in context of UI and
   frameworks.
2. Both Android Client and PC Server must be there on same
   wifi network, so that they can discover each other.
3. You must go with a Hello World Program of Android, if you do not have prior
   experience with same.
4. Networking Demos.
5. Also, threading will be required I think!